# Ubuntu installer only sees Windows 7 drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm running Windows 7 on an SSD and have an empty HDD which I'd like to install Ubuntu on. I've made a live USB using Rufus, booted Ubuntu off it and formatted my HDD to ext4 using gparted. Now, when I go to install Ubuntu on the ext4 partition I've created, the installer only shows my SSD as an option for installation, I've been looking around on this and other forums for a solution, but so far I've come up empty handed.

So the question is: How do I get my HDD to show up as an option for installation?

Thanks alot!

Comment: With multiple drives the installer shows a dropdown menu at some point. Perhaps you missed it?

Comment: No, I saw the menu, but it only contains the SSD

Comment: And yet you could format it in a live session? Can you see it with "something else"?

Comment: No, but is there a dropdown which isn't under "something else"? I'll look for it now  -EDIT Nope, no dropdown that I missed.